# Edit Print Page Margins

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to edit my printable page margins (change colors, etc). I have a row of merged cells that are gray, and I want this gray row to extend from one side of the page to the next. I do not want it to end at the margin.

I set the margins to 0" but I ended up with:

[image]

I need that gray bar to extend all the way across. How can I do this?

Comment: Most printers will not print to the edges of the paper (it depends on the printer).

Comment: I'm not looking to print the page; I actually want to save it as a PDF.